# Can tourists visit the Citadel of Alessandria?

Tags: italy, architecture

[A recent question about the Lille Citadelle](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10251) reminded me of my travels in Italy a decade ago where I was wandering around the outskirts of Alessandria and found a huge old citadel that was seemingly neglected and still in use by the military.

It turns out that [the Citadel of Alessandria is listed by UNESCO](http://whc.unesco.org/en/tentativelists/5013/) but I can't find any information about whether tourists can visit it these days.

[It has a homepage in Italian only](http://www.cittadelladialessandria.it/) which doesn't mention visiting. Wikipedia barely mentions it and Wikitravel and TripAdvisor don't mention it at all.

[Another site which also seems to be a homepage](http://www.cittadellaemarengo.com/homeFrameset-27.html) contains lots of photos, including at least one which looks like a tourist entrance and at least one other which looks it precludes civilians from entering.

**So are there any options to visit this citadel as of 2012?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must admit that there is a lack of information about the possibility to visit the cittadella.

After some search on the Internet I came out with [a site about Italy's historic monuments](http://www.imonumenti.it/592/m_1516.html) (again, only in Italian, sorry) stating that the cittadella is visitable from Monday to Sunday. Moreover, in the description it is said that the place has been open to visitors since 1990. This point is also supported by the fact that in the cittadella there is a museum of the weapons and uniforms of the Italian army.