# Which town/city is worth a day visit north/north-east of Paris?

Tags: france, sightseeing, recommendations

We are planning to stay in Paris for a couple of days in a month or so. After that I need to go to another city to meet with some family that comes from Germany (Giessen) and they don't want us to meet in Paris. It has to be somewhere north, because after that we'll go to Le Havre to catch a ferry the day after, and they will go back to Germany.

Obviously looking at Google Maps the first two options I found were Amiens and Saint-Quentin. I don't know if those are the best options or there is another place better to stay one day to tour around (we'll go with a baby, so we basically look for scenery rather than museums and things like that).

Comment: Compiègne might be an option (the town centre itself is nothing too impressive but you can go to the park and around the castle). Arras is a bit further away from Le Havre but also very nice to go around.

Comment: Thanks @Annoyed. That's the kind of information I was looking for.

Comment: Rouen is nice, and handy for you. Reims is nice, and handy for them. Lille is nice, and not that much further. Can you perhaps clarify a bit more how far you're willing to drive, what you're looking for, how you'll evaluate etc?

Comment: @Gagravarr, thanks for your answer. Our ferry will depart at 17:10 and we can leave the town/city we choose anytime like 7:00 or 8:00 that's not a problem so probably a maximum of 4 hours from Le Havre but if it's possible not more to the east than Amien. So the family from Germany don't have to drive too much.

Comment: Which bit of Germany are they coming from? That might influence things too

Comment: @Gagravarr I added it now in my question.. they come from Giessen

Comment: Reims or Amiens seem to make good options based on what you're saying. Going west they might pass Strasbourg, which is a nice place even though it's east of Le Havre

Comment: Will you and they be driving or taking trains?

Comment: @Gilles all of us will be driving

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your requirements, you've got pretty much 4 whole *régions* to select from. Probably easiest to tackle them in turn!

The best one for your family coming in from Rhine-Main is probably the [Champagne-Ardenne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champagne-Ardenne) region. City wise, try Reims. It'll be about a 3 hour drive for you to Le Havre afterwards, but you'll get to see a lovely old town, the cathedral, and you can taste Champagne! Also the option to meet in one of the villages outside Reims, if you'd rather countryside + Champagne tasting from one of the producers.
[image: From rnddave from www.flickr.com/photos/rnddave/6181816143/]

Not that different in travel time is the often overlooked *Nord Pas-De Calais*. Should be similar from Germany, and 3 hours to Le Havre again. The city of Lille is very nice, with some great art (modern and classic), an old town, and a [citadelle](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10251/can-you-visit-the-lille-citadelle) you can walk around the parks surrounding it, plus there's a zoo!
[image: From 89699688@N0 from www.flickr.com/photos/89699688@N02/8159356508/][image: From Brighton from www.flickr.com/photos/brighton/3034292741/]

Easier for you, but slightly further for them is *Picardie*. You've already mentioned the towns of Amiens and Saint-Quentin, but I'd suggest you follow Annoyed's advice and go to the nearby [Château de Pierrefonds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A2teau_de_Pierrefonds). If you've seen the BBC series Merlin, it's *that* castle! Maybe 2.5 hours to Le Havre, as it's slower roads.

[image: From jonathanjo from www.flickr.com/photos/jonathanjo/3821064653/]

Finally, good for you, less for them is *Haute-Normandie*. The town of Rouen is very nice, and very handy for Le Havre!

[image: 41099823@N00 from www.flickr.com/photos/41099823@N00/3950365699/][image: 41099823@N00 from www.flickr.com/photos/41099823@N00/3950195446/]]

Oh, and while Le Havre itself isn't as nice as somewhere like St Malo, it could be worth a brief stop on the way to the ferry!

Comment: Thanks.. that's a fantastic answers with beautiful options.. :)

Comment: Rouen is nice. We stopped there for crepes while driving from Paris to Caen. (Caen is a bit out of the way for you but also a nice town.)